# Is it possible to schedule a startup of an AWS instance from within the instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have an AWS instance that does some network data collection when it boots up.  It's important that the collection happen from a fresh public IP address -- I can't get useful data by running the collection again on the same address.

Right now, I can stop and then restart the instance in the EC2 console, and when it restarts, it gets a new IP address and collects more useful data.  (Just rebooting the instance doesn't assign a new IP -- I have to **stop** and then **start**.)

I know about time-based instance start scheduling, but what I'd like to do instead is schedule a restart *from within the instance itself*.  Sort of like an `at` job: `at now + 5 minutes restart-this-instance ; shutdown -h now`.

Alternatively, if there's a way to release and reallocate an instance's public IP, that would work too.

Comment: Side-comment: This sounds suspiciously like web-scraping where a website tries to prevent scraping by monitoring IP address. Please note that we do not encourage people to violate the terms and conditions of a website by using such methods.

Comment: Definitely not web-scraping, although I can see the common parts of the problem.  I'm actually collecting data on a different network system that I also operate: I want to know how caching and repeat traffic from previously-seen IP addresses affects the measured performance of the main system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest another approach...

The goal is to change Public IP address to measure how caching and repeat traffic from previously-seen IP addresses affects the measured performance of the main system.

Therefore, I would recommend:

- Have an Elastic IP address associated with the instance
- When a new IP address is desired:

  - **Disassociate** the Elastic IP address
  - **Release** the Elastic IP address
  - **Allocate** a *new* Elastic IP address
  - **Associate** the new Elastic IP address with the instance

You can use this script:

```
INSTANCE=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id/`

ALLOC=`aws ec2 describe-addresses --filters Name=instance-id,Values=$INSTANCE --query Addresses[].AllocationId --output text`

aws ec2 release-address --allocation-id $ALLOC

NEW=`aws ec2 allocate-address --domain vpc --query AllocationId --output text`

aws ec2 associate-address --allocation-id $NEW --instance-id $INSTANCE
```

Comment: That's certainly more straightforward!  Do you know whether there's a cost difference (considering that you have to pay for Lambda time over the free tier, and they charge you for all of the 2-3 minutes you have to wait for the instance to shut down)?

Comment: Huh, ElasticIP is free if the instance is running!  I think we have a winner!

Comment: Please note that any connections you have with the instance will be lost when the IP address changes. The above commands are best run as a script on the instance itself, rather than manually (eg by pasting the commands onto the command line).

Comment: @DaveM. BTW, it seems to be OK to release the address without first disassociating it. Let me know if you find otherwise.

Comment: I was getting a "still associated" error when I tried it that way, but I may have been confused with other EIP errors -- at one point, I had inadvertently allocated 5 addresses (they weren't getting released properly) so the AllocateAddress call was failing.

At any rate, I think it might be even cleaner to have a non-elastic public IP, then to allocate and associate an EIP briefly, and then disassociate/deallocate.  The VM will go back to a non-elastic public IP, which is what I need to happen, and I don't have to hold onto an EIP for most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible.

The command to Start the instance needs to be issued when the instance is Stopped. Therefore, the instance cannot issue the command to start itself.

It could, however, trigger something external to cause it to happen, such as creating a CloudWatch Rule or a Lambda function.

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  I had thought of using the "greybeard's Lambda:" send email to an external machine, which causes the machine to issue an `aws start` shortly thereafter, but using Lambda directly seems like an even cleaner solution (except for the hassle of figuring out how to do the Lambda part of it).

Comment: @DaveM. pick your favorite supported language and run with the Lambda solution.  Many of the Lambda runtime environments already include the AWS SDK and allow you to edit your function code right from the console (no packaging, zip files, etc., required), so for a simple task like this, you can literally write your code in the AWS console editor, deploy it, build and fire test events at it, and watch it do its thing.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe it's worth mentioning that in certain conditions (iirc if the instance is on a subnet with automatic public IP address assignment enabled and the instance is set to use the subnet settings), then you can force an IP change without a stop/start by temporarily attaching and then detaching an EIP that you set aside for this purpose.  When an EIP is attached, the old public IP goes away, and when it's detached, a new one from the pool automatically takes its place.

Comment: The Lambda approach seems to sort of work, but I'm stuck at the "reboot self" step: the `aws lambda invoke RestartSelf` CLI invocation doesn't return until the Lambda finishes, and the Lambda doesn't finish until the `instancesStart` finishes.  So I can't fire off the Lambda and then quickly `shutdown -h now`, and count on the Lambda to start me from stopped-state.   Is there a way for a Lambda to return a result to its caller, but continue processing asynchronously for a while?  It looks like as soon as you return a result, the Lambda driver system assumes that the function is done.

Comment: `--invocation-type Event` does it.  But the `shutdown -h now` is a lot slower than you expect.  The Lambda has to sleep for a couple of minutes to make sure the instance is shut down before it issues an `instancesStart` command.